# From what viewpoint do Omnioculars show past events?

Tags: harry-potter

Omnioculars are magical eyeglasses that allow viewing events slowed down, or replay past events.  They were introduced in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* chapter 7, and in chapter 8, Harry was watching the Quidditch match through them.  From what viewpoint do Omnioculars show events?

- Do they show the events from where the glasses were looking at the time the events happened?  That would make it not very useful in a sports match, where the spectators are sitting close to the events and have to turn their head to watch different parts of the stadium.
- Do they show the events from the viewpoint where the viewer is looking at when they are at the time of viewing?  That ability would be obviously overpowered and broken, since you could spy on any event that happens in a room that you can later get into.

Comment: Probably from the current viewpoint of the viewer.  And yes, this would make them the *thing to have* for any police detective-- unless of course they have some kind of time limit.

Comment: It's also possible (my memory of that device is hazy) that Omnioculars can only replay events that they themselves witnessed.  So you could replay the events of a match you were watching, but nothing before or after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## They show what happens in the direction they’re looking in.

Omnioculars work to slow down, replay, and explain the game, but not to record in all directions or watch the entire field. They’re never described or seen to record anything they weren’t pointed at.

> “Omnioculars,’ said the saleswizard eagerly. ‘You can replay action … slow everything down … and they flash up a play-by-play breakdown if you need it.”
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 8 (The Quidditch World Cup)*</sup></sub>

The Omnioculars can slow down and replay whatever was happening in the direction they were pointing at the time when they were pointed in that direction. They have to be pointed that way first.

> “That’s him, that’s him!’ yelled Ron, following Krum with his Omnioculars; Harry quickly focused his own.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 8 (The Quidditch World Cup)*</sup></sub>

They work something like a camera with slow motion and rewind function - they’ll replay and slow down the footage, but it’s only captured for the direction it was pointed at the time.

> “Seven green blurs swept onto the pitch; Harry spun a small dial on the side of his Omnioculars, and slowed the players down enough to read the word ‘Firebolt’ on each of their brooms, and see their names, embroidered in silver, upon their backs.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 8 (The Quidditch World Cup)*</sup></sub>

Throughout the game, people keep following certain things they want to see with their Omnioculars, so they need to be redirected if someone wants to look at anything moving, like a specific player.

> “What?’ Harry yelled, looking wildly around through his Omnioculars. ‘But Levski’s got the Quaffle!’
>
> ‘Harry, if you’re not going to watch at normal speed, you’re going to miss things!’ shouted Hermione, who was dancing up and down, waving her arms in the air while Troy did a lap of honour of the pitch.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 8 (The Quidditch World Cup)*</sup></sub>

Omnioculars don’t stop people having to turn their heads to watch things, not can they replay previous events that they weren’t directed at when they were happening.